# perfect tense to refer to the future

Tags: grammaticality

Some events are happening from time to time and I'd like a colleague of mine to notify me about the occurrence of those events next time they happen. So, I'm writing to that colleague:

> I'm looking forward to hearing from you about **an event having happened again**.

In response I'm expecting to receive a message of the following sort: "Hey, finally the event has happened again, log into the system and look at the consequences. "

My question is whether my message to the colleague is OK or not? What's wrong and how I could ask about the same in a grammatically correct way?

Comment: I want to thank everyone who has answered my question. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your message is ungrammatical because it uses a present perfect, which refers to a past interval of time, to refer to a future event.  You could say "... about a recurrence of such an event."

Answer (score 1):

Is the event something positive? If not it might be a little odd to say "looking forward to hearing from you" ..in case it happens again.

Anyway, why not write something like:

"Please do not hesitate/please feel free to inform/contact me in case it happens again."

Answer (score 1):

You are referring to the "past in the future" — that is, at some point in the future, the event will have happened.

Using *having happened* is perfectly grammatical, because the present tense (inasmuch as there is a present tense) is used to refer to future events: "It is happening tomorrow." There is no other construction which allows "past in the future": you have to have a past participle, which needs an auxiliary verb; and you need some means of putting that into the future. Simply using *has* is ungrammatical: you must use the present continuous.

However, one hears about some thing: that requires a noun, and so *having* becomes a gerund, and **that** needs *event's* to be possessive. Perhaps that's a bit pedantic, and not using the possessive would certainly be understood (even though it grates to my ears). I'd use *the* and not *an* because you obviously know what the expected event is.

> I'm looking forward to hearing from you about the event's having happened again.
>   I'm looking forward to hearing from you about the events' having happened again.
>   I'm looking forward to hearing from you about one of the events' having happened again.

Answer (score 0):

The message you should send to your colleague is

*I'm looking forward to hearing from you as soon as (or 'when' if it is not urgent) the event happens again*.

The response you would expect to receive would be as you gave it in the OP.

Comment: Dan, actually I'm interested only in the traces/consequences of the event. It will be important for me to know that the event of interest has happened shortly before the moment I log into a computer system.

Comment: Hi @Alexey.  I think I understand now.  I've altered my answer accordingly.